# Will socket 1155 cpu work in 775 mobo

Tags: cpu, motherboard, processor-socket

will **INTEL Celeron G440 BOX** (s. 1155) work in **ASROCK G31M-S R2.0**  (s. 775) motherboard?

I belive I heard that AM3 cpu can work in AM2 mobo is it the same case with intel.

Comment: Well that was pretty comprehensive.  Four "no" answers inside two minutes :)

Comment: I guess the same applies for vice versa..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they are not compatible by any stretch of the imagination.

The [AM2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM2) socket has 940 contacts while the [AM3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM3) socket has 941, but otherwise, the arrangement of contacts is the same. AM3 CPUs have only 938 contacts and can be used in AM2 and AM2+ sockets (assuming a BIOS update) because they were made to be backward-compatible. AM2 CPUs do not work in an AM3 system because they do not have the newer controllers.

Intel on the other hand changes greatly with newer version. The socket [775](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775) has 775 contacts while the socket [1155](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1155) has 1155 contacts. As you can see below, they are completely physically incompatible. In fact, even socket 1156 is incompatible with the (newer) socket 1155.

---

Socket AM2:
[image]

Socket AM3:
[image]

Socket 775:
[image]

Socket 1155:
[image]

Socket 1156:
[image]

Comment: +1 for having the most comprehesive answer, with pictures. I will go crosseyed trying to work out the difference between an LGA1155 and LGA1156 tho ;)

Comment: @Journeyman, thanks, I’m a visual learner. It’s actually quite easy to see the differences, just look at the notches and contacts around the edges; there are different numbers of pins in several of the groups.

Answer (score 6):

No, they are entirely incompatable pin outs - intel doesn't have backward compatibility between socket types - the [1155](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1155) has , well 1155 contacts and the [775](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775) has 775 contacts, even if they have the same processor dimensions. It simply will not work.

Answer (score 4):

**NO** they will not. AMD has released some chips that used the same physical socket with different specs that were sometimes compatible depending on chipset, cpu, and bios support.

Answer (score 3):

No. There are several reasons for that. Here are two:

1. LGA 775 CPUs have 775 pins while LGA 1155 CPUs have 1155 pins.
2. LGA 1155 CPUs access the memory directly while LGA 775 CPUs let the northbridge handle the RAM.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The physical socket is dramatically different. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1155).  So is all the underlying componentry to support the CPU.